# Numerical integrals and MATLAB precision

Tags: matlab

The following code

```
%% 
clc
clear 
%% 
M=4.5
lambda_0=0.332;
%% 
betats=0.05;
betan=betats/(lambda_0^(5/4));
f=@(x,y) y^(1/3)*(y^2+x^2)-1.001*sqrt((1-M^2)*y^2 + x^2);
alphan=real(fsolve(@ (y) y^(1/3)*(y^2+betan^2)-1.001*sqrt((1-M^2)*y^2 + betan^2),3));
alphats=alphan*(lambda_0^(5/4));
omegan=2.299*(alphan^(2/3));
omegats=(lambda_0^(3/2))*omegan;
gammats=sqrt((M^2-1)*alphats^2-betats^2);
gammats=-complex(0,1)*gammats;
%% 
beta1=0;
alpha1=1;
omega1=6;
gamma1=sqrt((M^2-1)*alpha1^2-beta1^2);
%% 
alpha2=alpha1-alphats;
beta2=beta1-betats;
omega2=omega1-omegats;
gamma2=sqrt((M^2-1)*alpha2^2-beta2^2);
%% 
N=25;
YMAX=150;
eta02=-i*omega2/((i*alpha2*lambda_0)^(2/3));
eta_inf2=((i*alpha2*lambda_0)^(1/3))*YMAX+eta02;
%% 
syms lu
aiprime(lu) = airy(1,lu);
aisecond(lu)= diff(airy(1,lu));

airy_D2=airy(1,eta02);
airy_DD2=vpa(aisecond(eta02));
airy_INT2=integral(@(n) airy(n),eta02,eta_inf2);
%% 
aa2=2*pi*complex(0,1)*gamma2*beta2*lambda_0*airy_D2/(alpha2*(alpha2^2+beta2^2)*airy_INT2-gamma2*lambda_0*airy_D2*(i*alpha2*lambda_0)^(2/3));
bb2=-aa2*airy(2,eta02)*airy_INT2/airy(eta02);

ai2=@(x) x*airy(x);
bi2=@(x) x*airy(2,x);

eta2=@(y) ((i*alpha2*lambda_0)^(1/3))*y+eta02;
Gi2=@(x) -(airy(2,x)*integral(@(n) airy(n),eta_inf2,x)-airy(x)*integral(@(n) airy(2,n),eta02,x));
W2=@(eta) aa2*Gi2(eta)+bb2*airy(eta);

W2VEC=arrayfun(W2,arrayfun(eta2,0:0.01:N));
plot(abs(W2VEC),0:0.01:N)
```

produces a noisy `W2VEC`. I think there is something very wrong either in the numerical integration or in the Airy functions.

The constants `aa2` and `bb2` have been chosen so that the two terms cancel each other at `0`, so a good result will verify `W2VEC(1)=0`.

What is going on here? Is it the accuracy of the integrals? It seems to me it has to do with the  precision for the integral calculation being lower than the magnitude of the numbers involved (10^15). Is this right? If so, how could I overcome such problem?

Comment: Some comments on what the code is calculating would be useful. Without understanding your entire algorithm it is difficult to understand what you mean by "noisy". What is the desired result? How "smooth" do you expect it to be?

Comment: I mean that W2VEC has to be continuous. The code basically computes a kind of "velocity" profile, which, as I mentioned, has to be zero at the bottom (y=0 or first component).

Comment: By the way, I didn't mention that Gi2 is the so-called "Scorer's Gi function", which isn't implemented in MATLAB, so I had to define it.

Comment: Did you try to debug your code?

Comment: Yep! I added a paragraph at the end of the question, explaining what I think the problem is. But I don't have a solution. In any case, you can all run it and get the same result than me! :)